# Cannot exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration for it is not auto-configuation class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` with the following code

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MainApplication {
}
```

It works well if I run it in SpringToolSuite4.
But once I package the project to jar and run it in alone environment, I get an error

```
2023-07-01 08:19:41,379 [main] ERROR SpringApplication -Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The following classes could not be excluded because they are not auto-configuration classes:
        - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.handleInvalidExcludes(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:222)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.checkExcludedClasses(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:208)
```

Someone can tell me what should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I removed `spring-boot-devtools` dependency and somehow it gets solved.